# Using custom assets as icons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, assets

I want to use custom assets instead of standard material icons for my Flutter app but I can't seem to get it working.
After searching google for a solution I found the **ImageIcon** widget that's supposed to provide exactly that but it throws the following error:

```
The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'.
```

I also tried (as per one other solution) to directly supply `Image.asset('..')` to the IconData field but that isn't assignable either.

This is my code:

```
IconData icon = ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/images/myimage.png'))
```

Since I am using other packages I don't want to go the route of creating my own containers..

Answer (score 0):

`IconData` is not a Widget, it's data which an `Icon` widget uses to display the icon.

`ImageIcon` can't be assigned to a variable of type `IconData` because it is, itself, already a widget. Simply use the `ImageIcon` directly in your widget tree, where you would have used an `Icon`.

```dart
// If you have something like this:
Row(
  children: [
    Icon(iconData),
    Text("Icon title"),
  ]
);

// Replace with this:
Row(
  children: [
    IconImage(AssetImage('assets/images/myimage.png')),
    Text("Icon title"),
  ]
)
```

Comment: Yeah see that's the thing, I'm using other packages that require me to pass an IconData value so I can't really use it as a Widget directly :/

Comment: Ah, in that case it seems you'd have to either contribute to the package to make it compatible, use your own fork (less advised for obvious reasons), or create a custom font with your assets which you could then pass to IconData

Answer (score 0):

ImageIcon cannot be assigned to IconData but you can use it as follows:

Container(
child:ImageIcon(
AssetImage("images/icon.png"),
color: Colors.red,
size: 24,
),
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).